# Push notification applicationIconBadgeNumber is not update in ios7

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I am using following code in app delegate to receive Remote notification but its applicationIconBadgeNumber (appear on app icon's top left corner in red/white) is not updating when app in background. when push notification received its appear in top corner of screen with slide animation , in notification payload Badge count is comming form server side perfectly.

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I have put following code

```
[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
```

Delegates for Remote notification :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSString *deviceTokenTrimmed = [[[[deviceToken description]
                                      stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]
                                     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
                                    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
    currentdeviceToken=deviceTokenTrimmed;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:deviceTokenTrimmed forKey:@"pushtoken"];
    NSLog(@"Device Token didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken :  %@",deviceTokenTrimmed);

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Device Token in FailToRegister RemoteNotifications ERROR %@",error);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        /***********code to show alert********/
        if (![[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey: @"alert"]] isEqualToString:@""] && [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey: @"alert"]]!=nil) {
            NSString *MSG =[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey: @"alert"]];
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:MSG delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }else{
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Notification Received." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }else{
      application.applicationIconBadgeNumber =[[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey: @"badge"]integerValue];
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found sol, Actually application:didReceiveRemoteNotification Not called when application in background, Its os responsibility to update applicationIconBadgeNumber when app in background, 
in my case actual problem was in payload. From Server End it was set as string but it should be integer. i am posting payload correct code which is written in php.

```
// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'sound.caf',
'badge' => $badge_count // Should be int type
);
```

Thanks, mokujin and Himanshu

Answer (score 0):

Use methods of `UIApplicationDelegate`

As `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method runs only when the application is in active state, the system calls *this* method regardless of the state of your app.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

       NSInteger badgeNumber = [application applicationIconBadgeNumber];
       [application setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:++badgeNumber];

    }
```

Comment: Thanks himanshu, but i have tried this also,this method not updating applicationIconBadgeNumber when app in background i debug this method with device control comes in this method when app is in foreground, 
am using ios 7.0 any other idea.

Comment: @tv.ashvin where did you stuck?

Comment: i think control is not comes in -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler; when app is in background when its in foreground count is update always..

Comment: Did you tried it after pressing home button and wait for 30 secs. Give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Whith the JSON payload you're actually setting the badge number. The only solution is to manage it server side by notifying the server each time a "notification" is read.

I gave a logic that how you can implement search in google there are so many article relevant to it.

Comment: Thanks mate , but in question last line i have mantion "in notification payload Badge count is comming form server side perfectly."

Comment: for updating badge from client side add this code in your didReceiveRemoteNotification method [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey: @"badgecount"] intValue];

Comment: hey i saw your code why are you updating badge when application is in active state put this line beyond if condition application.applicationIconBadgeNumber =[[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey: @"badge"]integerValue]; @tv.ashvin

Comment: I want to update count when app in Background, when app in Foreground notification msg will appear to user in Alert view.