# PushNotification badge number not showing when my app is not active?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I'm using `Urbanairship` for APNS in my app and everything going well but app badge number is not displaying when my app is not running, however when app is active and push is received then badge number is displayed over app icon.

Here is my code as following:

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
     UAConfig *config = [UAConfig defaultConfig];
        [UAirship takeOff:config];
        // Request a custom set of notification types
        [UAPush shared].notificationTypes = (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                             UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                             UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                             UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability);

        return YES;
    }
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {

        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Error: %@", err];
        NSLog(@"%@",str);

    }

    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
        NSLog(@"Received notification: %@", userInfo);
        //[self addMessageFromRemoteNotification:userInfo];

        NSString* alertValue = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"badge"];
        NSLog(@"my message-- %@",alertValue);
        int badgeValue= [alertValue intValue];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:badgeValue];


    }
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** i also tried with -

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    NSInteger badgeNumber = [application applicationIconBadgeNumber];
    [application setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:++badgeNumber];
}
```

but still no luck, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: did you check your server side there is properly setting badge value.? what is log print `[alertValue intValue]`?

Comment: This is the log- Received notification: {
    "_" = "eHa-4LMVEeOdIJDiugJkgA";
    aps =     {
        alert = "This is a test push from MAdept";
        badge = 21;
    };
} and [alertValue intValue] is 21.

Comment: try ones with put static number  `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];` what happend with this..?

Comment: still no luck, i think problem is not here because it showing when push received while app is running and i press the home button without clicking on push alert.

Comment: Beside your problem, make sure when you do this `application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;` server also resets the count.

Comment: is anyone there who can notice the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317701/apple-push-notification-not-changing-icon-badge-automatically)

If you also register `UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability` then remove it and retry.

Comment: For iOS 8 and higher you must use registerUserNotificationSettings method
[see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021113/how-to-correctly-set-application-badge-value-in-ios-8)

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON needs to be in following format.

What you have won't properly convert into an NSDictionary.

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got your Notification",
        "badge" : 1,
        "sound" : 'default'
    },
    "acme1" : "bar",
    "acme2" : 42

}
```

Please reference the [Push Notification Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1).

Comment: Thanks for answer but i'm sending this push from urbanairship site and the JSON is valid.

Comment: you can also refer this for how to handle push notification in background http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116282/handling-push-notifications-when-app-is-not-running

Comment: sorry this is not related to my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code may it helps you.

UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];

```
if (state == UIApplicationStateActive)
{

   NSLog(@"Received notification: %@", userInfo);
    //[self addMessageFromRemoteNotification:userInfo];

    NSString* alertValue = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"badge"];
    NSLog(@"my message-- %@",alertValue);
    int badgeValue= [alertValue intValue];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:badgeValue];
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22248149/push-notification-applicationiconbadgenumber-is-not-update-in-ios7/22248765#22248765 check this and see op's answer

Comment: i tried everything but badge not shows when app is not running.

Comment: what is the value you are getting in badgevalue