# How to correctly set application badge value in iOS 8?

Tags: ios8

Old method

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:count];
```

is now gives error `Attempting to badge the application icon but haven't received permission from the user to badge the application`.

Then I tried to use new API (that I'm think is related to badge value)

```
CKModifyBadgeOperation * operation = [[CKModifyBadgeOperation alloc] initWithBadgeValue:50];
[operation setModifyBadgeCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
      NSLog(@"%@", error);
}];
[operation start];
```

But I'm receiving error `<CKError 0x165048a0: "Not Authenticated" (9/1002); "This request requires an authenticated account">`

How to set badge or receive some new permissions?

Comment: @Daij-Djan Why did you do that? It's completely changes the sense of question.

Comment: whatever rolled it back

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In addition to Daij-Djan's answer: it's possible to stack the enums so you can request them all at once. Like follows:

```
UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
```

[Debug output mentions I should ask for Application Badge permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028172/debug-output-mentions-i-should-ask-for-application-badge-permission)

Comment: Well...this site thrives because people are asking things that are obvious to others :)

Comment: yes but this isn't an answer to this question :D Im not saying it isn't valid or useful but think if you would see THIS when searching for how to set the badge? ;)

Answer (score 36):

to modify the badge under ios8 you have to ask for permissions

```
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Badge, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
```

or in objC

```
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeBadge categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
```

Comment: Is there a way to programatically determine if the permission has been granted? As long as it's not a crash I guess setting the badge and failing is fine.

Comment: @PsychoDad, to determine if permission has been granted, you need to implement the application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings: method and check the settings provided there. If something's missing, then permission was not granted.

Comment: @PsychoDad: you can use the method suggested by mcsheffrey to get the permissions granted by user when you displayed the alert. However, the user can later go to settings and disable some permissions. So, another way to get the current permissions is:

`UIUserNotificationSettings *currentSettings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings]`

Answer (score 22):

Additional info for previous posts (in complete to `registerUserNotificationSettings`):

Apple makes new API for registering notifications and working with badges.

See WWDC 2014 session [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=713) , [text version](http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/713)
and [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/registerUserNotificationSettings).

User can change permissions for every `UIUserNotificationType` (`UIUserNotificationTypeBadge`, `UIUserNotificationTypeSound`, `UIUserNotificationTypeAlert`) in Settings.

Before changing badge you must check permissions.

Code sample from my AppDelegate:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0

- (BOOL)checkNotificationType:(UIUserNotificationType)type
{
    UIUserNotificationSettings *currentSettings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];

    return (currentSettings.types & type);
}

#endif

- (void)setApplicationBadgeNumber:(NSInteger)badgeNumber
{
    UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    #ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    // compile with Xcode 6 or higher (iOS SDK >= 8.0)

    if(SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"8.0"))
    {
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeNumber;
    }
    else
    {
        if ([self checkNotificationType:UIUserNotificationTypeBadge])
        {
            NSLog(@"badge number changed to %d", badgeNumber);
            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeNumber;
        }
    else
        NSLog(@"access denied for UIUserNotificationTypeBadge");
    }

    #else
    // compile with Xcode 5 (iOS SDK < 8.0)
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeNumber;

    #endif
}

#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
```

The `CurrentUserNotificationSettings` method is available in the UI application instance and will give you the most up-to-date user notification preferences.

Working with badge number:

```
[self setApplicationBadgeNumber:0];
```

instead of

```
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

**PS:** Checking at compiling (`#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0`) due to the need to build in Xcode5 and Xcode6. 
If you do not have this need, the code can be simplified.

Answer (score 1):

I write a class to handle it when I use swift:

```
class ZYUtility
{
    /// Set badge
    class func setApplicationBadgeNumber(badge: Int) {
        if ZYUtility.SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO("8.0") {
            if UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings().types & UIUserNotificationType.Badge != nil {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = badge
            } else {
                println("No permission to set badge number")
            }
        } else {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = badge
        }
    }

    /// System check
    class func SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(version: String) -> Bool {
        return UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.compare(version,
            options: NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame
    }

    class func SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(version: String) -> Bool {
        return UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.compare(version,
            options: NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
    }

    class func SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(version: String) -> Bool {
        return UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.compare(version,
            options: NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch) != NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
    }

    class func SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(version: String) -> Bool {
        return UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.compare(version,
            options: NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
    }

    class func SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(version: String) -> Bool {
        return UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.compare(version,
            options: NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch) != NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

update to 8.3, ObjC: we should add Daij-Djan script to replace NSLog(@"access denied for UIUserNotificationTypeBadge"); in Spidy & KepPM solution above. Hope this help s.o.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).