# iOS App not registering for push notifications

Tags: ios8, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to register for push notifications in my iOS app. But it is calling neither the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` nor `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` callback methods. I have revoked and regenerated the provisioning profile for the app.

I am using iOS8 and I have enabled the following background modes in my Info.plist

1. App registers for location updates
2. App downloads content in response to push notifications
3. App downloads content from the network

The code is:

```
-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Failed to register for push");
}

-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"did succeed in register for push");

    // Get the device token string
    const char* data = [deviceToken bytes];
    NSMutableString* token = [NSMutableString string];

    for (int i = 0; i < [deviceToken length]; i++) {
        [token appendFormat:@"%02.2hhX", data[i]];
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:token forKey:@"DeviceToken"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    [self respondToEventNotification:userInfo];

}

-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

    [self respondToEventNotification:userInfo];

}
```

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690121/how-to-properly-set-push-notifications-in-ios/29690305#29690305

Comment: Did you enable pushnotifications option for the appid in developer account ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you register your app with `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method for `iOS8` like,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge
                                                                                         |UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound
                                                                                         |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    }
    else
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

}
```

You have to consider registration process of Push Notification in iOS8.

May this help you.

Comment: It worked. Although I had to use `UIUserNotificationTypeSound` as `UIRemoteNotificationBadge`, etc are deprecated